# Creating "uniform" variables in a module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

I'm quite new to the concept of module patterns. I managed to implement the core features of my HTML5 game, but I can't figure out a good way to make certain variables available to every function of that game.

Here is a short pseudo example which should make it more clear:

```
var Game = {};

Game.player = (function() {

    //...

    return {
        update : update,
        draw : draw        
    };
});

Game.main = (function() {

    var player = new Game.player();

    // needed by player
    var gravity = 1.0,
        loop,
        canvas,
        ctx,
        key_inputs;

    //...

    return {
        init : init,
        pause : pause,
        play : play        
    };
});

var game = new Game.main();
game.init();
​
```

Comment: can you clarify what the question is?

Comment: @jbabey How does the player get access to the variables of the main object without having to pass every single variable ? The update function of the player for example needs to know the gravity and the pressed keys etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code scoped to your `Player` function needs to use some variables declared in your `Game` function, you have three options:

- Move them to a higher scope (which would be global in this case, so not recommended)
- Pass them as parameters to the player (not great since they won't be updated in `Player` if they change in `Game`)
- Create a `getter` function in `Game` that returns the current state of the variables to the `Player` function.

You'll also need to pass the instance of the `Game` to the `Player` so it knows which `Game` to grab it's data from.

Here's an example of #3 (the one I would try):

```
Game.main = (function() {
    var player = new Game.player(this);

    // needed by player
    var gravity = 1.0,
        loop,
        canvas,
        key_inputs;

    var getSettings = function () {
        return {
            gravity: gravity,
            loop: loop,
            canvas: canvas,
            key_inputs: key_inputs
        };
    };

    return {
        init : init,
        pause : pause,
        play : play,
        getSettings: getSettings        
    };
});
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but the original code had both `player` and `main` as the objects, in the `Game` pseudo-namespace. So there is no `Game` object, per se.

Comment: I thought about this solution. Though wouldn't it be hardcoded if I pass the reference of the `Game` object (`game`) ? Edit: Ah no it's not.

Comment: @elias94xx: there's no hard-coding. If you were to create a new `main` object, then the `player` object inside of it would point to that new object, not the other game object.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide getter and setter methods in `Game.main`. You should pass an instance of `Game.main` to the `Game.player` constructor. Then `Game.player` can use the getter/setter methods on its instance of `Game.main` to access those variables.

Make sure that your architecture is sound and that you only share what you need to share.

Comment: I really need to know how to properly pass an instance. Is this the right way ? http://jsfiddle.net/PJD5X/

Because `this` inside the main function won't work.

Comment: @elias94xx: why not just do it when you declare player on the first line of your main function? Scope is weird in JavaScript, and that's why the `this` is not what you are expecting. I modified your jsfiddle with what I imagine will do what you want.

Comment: @elias94xx: oops, it turns out you can just modify the fiddles like that. I think what you have is actually good enough, given the model you are using. Here's my own version: http://jsfiddle.net/crmsN/1/

Comment: Oh right, I can just pass the get function instead of a whole game reference. Sometimes I think way to complicated.. Thanks! ;)